# How do I download and save an image from http address in Common Lisp/dexador?

Tags: http, common-lisp

How would you download an image from a website and save it to the package folder in  Common Lisp? I am having difficulty looking for such function in dexador's documentation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That would be an awesome first contribution to dexador :]

Answer (score 6):

You get a byte vector back, so just save it:

```
(let ((bytes (dex:get uri)))
  (with-open-file (out filename
                       :direction :output
                       :if-exists :supersede
                       :if-does-not-exist :create
                       :element-type 'unsigned-byte)
    (write-sequence bytes out)))
```

If you have too much data, you might want to use a buffered stream copy:

```
(let ((byte-stream (dex:get uri :want-stream t))
      (buffer (make-array buffer-size :element-type 'unsigned-byte)))
  (with-open-file (out filename
                       :direction :output
                       :if-exists :supersede
                       :if-does-not-exist :create
                       :element-type 'unsigned-byte)
    (loop :for p := (read-sequence buffer byte-stream)
          :while (plusp p)
          :do (write-sequence buffer out :end p))))
```

Comment: First case can be easier if use `alexandria:write-byte-vector-into-file`.

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly improved first version from Svante's answer:

```
(alexandria:write-byte-vector-into-file (dex:get "https://httpbin.org/image/png")
                                        #P"/tmp/myfile"
                                       :if-exists :supersede)
```

And this is slightly simplified version of his second version:

```
(serapeum:write-stream-into-file (dex:get "https://httpbin.org/image/png"
                                          :want-stream t)
                                 #P"/tmp/myfile"
                                 :if-exists :supersede)
```

Alexandria and Serapeum both are collections of little helpers to simplify such tasks.